# How can I turn a list of lists into a string with a new line for each list and no commas

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

So I have a list of lists:

```
ListofLists = [["item1list1","item2list1","item3list1"],["item1list2","item2list2","item3list2"]]
```

I want to convert this into a string that looks like this:

```
"item1list1 item2list1 item3list1
 item1list2 item2list2 item3list2"
```

How can I get the string to have a new line between the two lists and just a space between the individual items of each list item.

I've looked about and found this

```
stringlist = "".join(str(x) for x in ListofLists)
```

But it is not giving me the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
#          v space (between individual items)
'\n'.join(' '.join(sub) for sub in ListofLists)
# ^ new line (between sublists)
```

So we use a generator `' '.join(sub) for sub in ListOfLists` that will, for every sublist `sub`, generate a string by joining the elements together with spaces between them.

Then we join these strings per sublist together with `'\n'`. The `'\n'` is a *new line character*. If you `print(..)` the result, you will obtain:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(sub) for sub in ListofLists))
item1list1 item2list1 item3list1
item1list2 item2list2 item3list2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate a loop in list and `join` its element.

```
ListofLists = [["item1list1","item2list1","item3list1"],["item1list2","item2list2","item3list2"]]
for i in ListofLists:
    print " ".join(i)
```

Output:

```
item1list1 item2list1 item3list1
item1list2 item2list2 item3list2
```